# python multiprocessing starmap vs apply_async, which is faster?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

Suppose I have these two approaches to accomplish the same task:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(4)

def func(*args):
    # do some slow operations
    return something

dates = ['2011-01-01', ' 2011-01-02', ... , '2017-01-01']
other_args = [1, 2, 3, 'c', 'test', 'pdf')]
# approach 1:
res = [pool.apply_async(func, [day] + other_args) for day in dates]
list_of_results = [x.get() for x in res]

# approach 2: create an iterable of iterables
args = [[day] + other_args for day in dates]
list_of_results = pool.starmap(func, args)
```

I realize apply_async returns immediately, however, x.get() might still block the main thread if func has not finished running...Will there necessarily be a performance difference between these two methods?

Comment: The whole point on using async methods is to avoid waiting for the result, as they are going to be used later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, `starmap` does pretty much what you did in the first approach. It's just a convenience wrapper. The `map` family of functions is provided to comply with the functional programming paradigms which many developers are used to.

They offer some nice functionalities such as the split of the iterables in chunks to minimize IPC. The performance benefits might come from this optimization but it will depends on your computation cost per single element.

I'd recommend to stick to what is more readable and, only if performance is a **real** concern, to benchmark and evaluate the results.